# Blogdown on Shiny Server

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, shiny-server, blogdown

I try to make basic `blogdown::new_site()`.
 On local PC all looking good, but when I try make same on Sniny-Server something going wrong. 
Look like can't find css files or something like that.

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]

Comment: It is a known issue: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/124

Comment: @YihuiXie thx a lot